# How to put get directions button on CustomPinView on iOS 6?

Tags: button, maps, ios6, directions

I can't find any documentation explaining where can I add this button to my pinview. For the ones who do not know what I am talking about, here is a image:

[image: It is the green button with a car in it]

Comment: Have you found out? I am looking for the same thing.